# Ball doesn't move when space is pressed

Tags: python, pygame

Does anybody see the problem in this code? Trying to make the ball/bullet come out of the left paddle and disappear once it hits the right paddle but when I try running the code I don't see the ball in general. I think its hidden behind the left paddle but its not moving either when I'm space. I am trying to make a game where the left player would should bullets and the right player would try to dodge them. Now I'm stuck at the bullet. Please help. Thanks!

```
import pygame 

pygame.init()

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 720
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height),0,0)

pygame.display.set_caption("PongGame")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#background
background = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/background.png")

#paddle image
paddle = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/paddle.png")
paddle_size = paddle.get_rect().size

#left paddle
left_paddle_width = paddle_size[0]
left_paddle_height = paddle_size[1]
left_paddle_xpos = 10
left_paddle_ypos = (screen_height/2 - left_paddle_height/2)

to_x = 0
to_y = 0

character_speed = 10

#right paddle
right_paddle_width = paddle_size[0]
right_paddle_height = paddle_size[1]
right_paddle_xpos = screen_width - right_paddle_width - 10
right_paddle_ypos = (screen_height/2 - left_paddle_height/2)

to_y_2 = 0
# ball
bullet = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/ball.png")
bullet_size = bullet.get_rect().size
bullet_width = bullet_size[0]
#make the bullet be able to shoot multiple at the same time
bullets = []
#bulllet speed
bullet_speed = 15


running = True
while running:
   dt = clock.tick(60)
   
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         running = False
   #left paddle
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            to_y -= character_speed
         elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
             to_y += character_speed
         elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            bullet_ypos = left_paddle_ypos
            bullet_xpos = left_paddle_xpos
            bullets.append([bullet_xpos, bullet_ypos])

      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            to_y = 0
   #right paddle
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            to_y_2 -= character_speed
         elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
             to_y_2 += character_speed

      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            to_y_2 = 0

   left_paddle_ypos += to_y
   right_paddle_ypos += to_y_2

   bullets = [ [w[0] - bullet_speed, w[1]] for w in bullets] #shoot the bullet 

   bullets = [ [w[0], w[1]] for w in bullets if w[0] == right_paddle_xpos and w[1] == right_paddle_ypos]

   #barrier for the paddles to not go outside the screen.
   if left_paddle_ypos < 0:
      left_paddle_ypos =  0
   
   if left_paddle_ypos > screen_height - left_paddle_height:
      left_paddle_ypos = screen_height - left_paddle_height

   window.blit(background,(0,0))
   
   window.blit(paddle, (left_paddle_xpos,left_paddle_ypos))
   window.blit(paddle, (right_paddle_xpos, right_paddle_ypos))

   for bullet_xpos, bullet_ypos in bullets:      
      window.blit(bullet, (bullet_xpos, bullet_ypos))

   pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try running it through a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes required:

- Remove this line. It clears the bullet list before the bullets are shown.

  `#bullets = [ [w[0], w[1]] for w in bullets if w[0] == right_paddle_xpos and w[1] == right_paddle_ypos]`
- Change this line (`-` to `+`). It sends the bullets in the wrong direction.

  `bullets = [ [w[0] + bullet_speed, w[1]] for w in bullets] #shoot the bullet`

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to make the ball/bullet... disappear once it hits the right paddle

So, I assume this is the line intended to have that effect:

```
bullets = [ [w[0], w[1]] for w in bullets if w[0] == right_paddle_xpos and w[1] == right_paddle_ypos]
```

Read it more carefully: for each of the bullet positions, we will check `if` it is positioned *exactly where the right paddle is* (i.e., top-left corners coincide!), and if so, *keep that* one unmodified; *everything else is discarded*.

You need to [use proper collision logic](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect), and you need to keep bullets that have *not* collided with the absorber.

Incidentally:

```
     elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bullet_ypos = left_paddle_ypos
        bullet_xpos = left_paddle_xpos
        bullets.append([bullet_xpos, bullet_ypos])
```

How exactly did you want new bullets to be positioned, relative to the left paddle? How does this code say they will be positioned?

bullets = [ [w[0] - bullet_speed, w[1]] for w in bullets] #shoot the bullet

Which way do you want the bullet to move, if its speed is positive? Which way will it actually move, according to this logic?